# How to pass more than one parameters from views.py to forms and get them in forms.py and add to HiddenInput fields in django 2.1.7?s

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new to Django and I am trying to add comments for a post in a blog in Django 2.1. When adding comments to a post, I need to save the user_id of logged in user and post_id of that comment. I defined my comment model with relations to post and user models as below:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_by', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    post_name = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='post_name', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

There is the template code where I use CommentForm and get the data comments from the user:

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}    
  <form method="POST" action="  ">
      <div class="form-group"></div>
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type='submit' class="btn btn-success" />
  </form>
{% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Add Comment</a>
{% endif %}
```

I used `__init__()` method in CommentForm to get the post_id and user_id. This method works fine for first parameter *'post'* and gets post_id and saves it, but not is working for getting user_id *'create'*. I want to get the session user_id and pass it from views.py to forms.py and save it with comment creation same as getting post_id. Is it possible to pass more than one parameter from views.py and pass it to form and get them in that form to save to that model?
Here is the code which I wrote for doing above functionality:

**veiws.py**

My method for creating comments:

```
def details(request, id):

    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, post=instance.id) # get and pass post_id of related post
    if  request.method == 'POST':
         if request.user:
             user = request.user.id
             form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, create=user) # Wants to get the session user id and pass it to forms.py
```

**forms.py**

In my CommentForm I have following method:

```
def __init__(self, args, *kwargs):
        post = kwargs.pop('post', '')
        super(CommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if post:
            self.fields['post_name'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Post.objects.filter(pk=post))

         create = kwargs.pop('create', '')
         print(kwargs)
         super(CommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         if create:
             self.fields['created_by'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Comments.objects.filter(created_by=create))
```

Above code works for first parameter *'post'* but not for second parameter *'create'* and give the *"name 'create' is not defined"* error.

Comment: I don't understand what you have tried to do here. Why do you have two `__init__` methods?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to get the post_id which the comments is related and save it to model and I also want to get the user_id which is currently logged in. Actually fields for 'post_name' and 'created_by' are HiddenInput in Comment model. Therefore I can't get them from the template. So I tried to use __init__() method and get those fields from session and related post.

Comment: But that didn't answer the question. Why did you write two separate methods with the same name? Why do you think that would work? Why, for example, wouldn't you get both values in the same method?

Comment: In fact there are lots of very very strange things about your code. Why do you redefine `form` in your view if the method is POST?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Sorry for the mess code. Actually the second def __init_() was comment in my code, but when I copy and pasted here I forgot to in-comment that part by mistake. The form redefine was also for testing and I know that's unnecessary. As I mentioned, I am new to Django and I searched and read a lot about my problem, but can't find a way to do what I wanted.

Comment: So please edit your question to show your actual code, and explain your problem properly.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I edited my code and add Comments model and template code where I used the CommentForm to get comment from the user. Would you please take a look?

Comment: This code is still not valid, as it has indentation errors. Nevertheless, there doesn't appear to be a time in your view that you are instantiating the form with both parameters.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Sir I don't know how to do that. If you mean I didn't instantiate these two fields in template, I should say that, I don't want to do that at there because I don't want to get those fields data explicitly.  I want to get those two fields in views.py and pass them to forms.py.